# is it possible to do non-overlapping shadows?

Tags: css, box-shadow

If you put your mouse over the pill-shaped thing, It'll move over the circle (what I want to happen), but the shadow of the circle will remain visible.
I want the shadows to not affect each other, but still be transparent.

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
#circle1, #circle2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
#pill1, #pill2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
#pill2 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(180, 180, 180, 1), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
}
#circle2 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(180, 180, 180, 1), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
}
@keyframes animation {
  0% {right: 0px;}
  100% {right: 58px;}
}
#pill1:hover, #pill2:hover {
  animation: animation 0.5s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1"></div>
<div id="pill1"></div>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<div id="pill2"></div>
```

I forgot to mention something, it's supposed to be an animation. I put it in here as a transition but it wasn't working. I just fixed it, so it's now an animation.

The one on the right is what I want to happen, but that is max opacity.

Comment: i updated my answer, by the way no need animation as you can use transition ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the shadow on hover of the `circle` and make its z-index higher than the `pill` to catch its hover state:

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
#circle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
}
#pill {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
#circle:hover + #pill, #pill:hover {
  right: 58px;
}
#circle:hover {
  box-shadow:none;
}
/*Added this to avoid the issue of hovering only the pill and not the circle*/
#circle:hover::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="pill"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

By the way you can simplify your code like this:

*I also included the transition*

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
#circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-color: white;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
#circle:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:80px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-color: white;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}
#circle:hover::before {
  left:0;
}
#circle:hover {
  box-shadow:none;
}
/*Added this to avoid glitchs*/
#circle:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {left: 80px;}
  100% {left: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```